# Ubuntu Server KVM - Shield 3 of 4 NICs from Host

Tags: networking, ubuntu, linux-kvm

I use 4 different networks (1 for server-host) and one for each of the 3 vms.
Those 4 networks are completely shielded from each other and MUST NOT have access to one another.

What im trying to accomplish is on the host system, just to give the host itself access to the first nic, the other 3 must not be visible (or active) so the host can remain within its network and is completely firewalled.

the 3 vms use 3 independent DMZ networks and must not access the main network at all costs. the same goes for the host, it may not be accessed in any way from one of the dmz's.

How do i need to setup my network in ubuntu server with kvm?

Answer (score 0):

How about your vm network interface setting?

1. Host device
2. Specify share device name (Bridge, must be created from host)

if you use different networks, you can try host device mode. 
e.g.

- vm1 --> eth1
- vm2 --> eth2
- vm3 --> eth3

Answer (score 0):

Use VTD pass through. Pass the NICs directly to the guest machines. This way the Host OS will never see the NICs or any traffic on them.

If you need to share the NICs because more than one guest needs to be on each network, then you must use bridges. Preventing the host from appearing on the bridge is tricky. Note that it is not as simple as not assigning an IP address. Some suggestions are here: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-linux-bridge-isolation